# Creating a color map from a list of RGB colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I want to create a color map in python similar to this image:
[image]

but my map only consists of 3 rows and 4 columns. And I want to assign a certain color value to each square using RGB values. I have tried this code

```
colors=np.array([[0.01, 0.08, 0.01], [0.01, 0.16, 0.01], [0.01, 0.165, 0.01], [0.01, 0.3, 0.01],
                 [0.01, 0.2, 0.01], [0.666, 0.333, 0.01], [0.01, 0.165, 0.01], [0.01, 0.3, 0.01],
                 [0.01, 0.2, 0.01], [0.666, 0.333, 0.01], [0.01, 0.165, 0.01], [0.01, 0.3, 0.01]])


fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(colors)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

but the output does not match my expectations. It seems that with this method I cannot use the RGB values to represent the color for a square. Can anyone help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: What do you get instead of your expectations? What are your expectations?

Comment: Is the array you have shown the 2D data you want to plot? If so, you haven't specified any colors. Or is it supposed to be the colors? If so, what is the 2D data you want to plot?

Comment: @mkrieger1 as I said I want a color map consists of 3 rows and 4 columns but my figure shows a map of 12 rows and 3 columns. You can try to copy and run my code to see the output. Sorry that I cannot post the image in this comment section.

Comment: You have a `(12,3)` colors array, while you need a `(3, 4, 3)` image, one RGB color per pixel.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, the array above is the color data that I want to plot. I'm trying to represent RGB values for each square so it should have 12 squares divided into 3 rows and 4 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `(12,3)` colors array, while you need a `(4, 3, 3)` image, one RGB color per pixel.

```
import numpy as np  # type: ignore
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # type: ignore

colors = np.array(
    [
        # this is the first row
        [
            # these are the 3 pixels in the first row
            [0.01, 0.08, 0.01],
            [0.01, 0.16, 0.01],
            [0.01, 0.165, 0.01],
        ],
        [
            [0.01, 0.3, 0.01],
            [0.01, 0.2, 0.01],
            [0.666, 0.333, 0.01],
        ],
        [
            [0.01, 0.165, 0.01],
            [0.01, 0.3, 0.01],
            [0.01, 0.2, 0.01],
        ],
        # this is the fourth row
        [
            [0.666, 0.333, 0.01],
            [0.01, 0.165, 0.01],
            [0.01, 0.3, 0.01],
        ],
    ]
)
print(colors.shape)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(colors)
ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()
```

Rearrange the data as you need in rows/columns.